# Apache BEAM pipeline IllegalArgumentException - Timestamp skew?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, fluentd

I have an existing BEAM pipeline that is handling the data ingested (from Google Pubsub topic) by 2 routes. The 'hot' path does some basic transformation and stores them in Datastore, while the 'cold' path performs fixed hourly windowing for deeper analysis before storage.

So far the pipeline has been running fine until I started to do some local buffering on the data before publishing to Pubsub (so data arrives at Pubsub may be a few hours 'late'). The error that gets thrown is as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot output with timestamp 2018-06-19T14:00:56.862Z. Output timestamps must be no earlier than the timestamp of the current input (2018-06-19T14:01:01.862Z) minus the allowed skew (0 milliseconds). See the DoFn#getAllowedTimestampSkew() Javadoc for details on changing the allowed skew.
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.checkTimestamp(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:463)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.outputWithTimestamp(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:429)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.WithTimestamps$AddTimestampsDoFn.processElement(WithTimestamps.java:138)
```

It seems to be referencing the section of my code (withTimestamps method) that performs the hourly windowing as below:

```
Window<KV<String, Data>> window = Window.<KV<String, Data>>into
                (FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(1)))
    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(pastEndOfWindow()))
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
    .discardingFiredPanes();

PCollection<KV<String, List<Data>>> keyToDataList = eData.apply("Add Event Timestamp", WithTimestamps.of(new EventTimestampFunction()))
    .apply("Windowing", window)
    .apply("Group by Key", GroupByKey.create())
    .apply("Sort by date", ParDo.of(new SortDataFn()));
```

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what I've done wrong here. Is it because the data is arriving late that is throwing the error? As I understand, if the data arrives late past the allowed lateness, it should be discarded and not throw an error like the one I'm seeing.

Wondering if setting an unlimited timestampSkew will resolve this? The data that's late can be exempt from analysis, I just need to ensure that errors don't get thrown that will choke the pipeline. There's also nowhere else where I'm adding/ changing the timestamps for the data so I'm not sure why the errors are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DoFn is using [“outputWithTimestamp”](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.WindowedContext.html#outputWithTimestamp-OutputT-org.joda.time.Instant-) and you are trying to set a timestamp which is older than the input element’s timestamp. Typically timestamps of output elements are derived from inputs, this is important to ensure the correctness of the watermark computation.

You may be able to workaround this by increasing both the timestamp skew and the windwing allowed lateness, however, some data may be lost, it is for you to determine if such loss is acceptable in your scenario.

Another alternative is not to use output with timestamp and instead use the PubSub message timestamp to process each message. Then, output each element as a KV, where the RealTimestamp is computed in the same way you are currently processing the timestamp (just don’t use it in “WithTimestamps”), GroupByKey and write the KV to Datastore.

Other questions you can ask yourself are:

- Why are the input elements associated to a most recent timestamp than the output elements?
- Do you really need to Buffer that much data before publishing to PubSub?